# Linear Transformation, Nullspace, and Range

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over a field $F$. Suppose $P:V\to V$ is a linear transformation such that $P^2=P$. Such a linear transformation is called a projection.

Prove that, for any $v \in V$, there exist unique vectors $n, w \in V$ such that $v=n+w$, where $n \in N(P)$ (nullspace) and $w \in R(P)$ (range).

I really have no idea how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $v\in V$, we obviously have $P(v)\in R(P)$. If we set $w=P(v)$ and $n=v-w$, then $P(n)=P(v)-P(w)=P(v)-P^2(v)=P(v)-P(v)=0$, i.e. $n\in N(P)$. Notice that both $n$ and $w$ are uniquely determined by $v$ and $P$, and satisfy the desired conditions.